# Mutually recursive module and functor in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have defined an interface `A` to be used by several functors, and notably by `MyFunctor` :

```
module type A = sig
    val basic_func: ...
    val complex_func: ...
end

module MyFunctor :
    functor (SomeA : A) ->
struct
    ...
    let complex_impl params =
        ...
        (* Here I call 'basic_func' from SomeA *)
        SomeA.basic_func ...
        ...
end
```

Now I want to define a module `B` with implements the interface `A`. In particular, the implementation of `complex_func` should use `basic_func` through `complex_impl` in `MyFunctor` :

```
module B = struct
    let basic_func = ...

    let complex_func ... =
        let module Impl = MyFunctor(B) in
        Impl.complex_impl ...
end
```

However, this code doesn't compile as `B` is not fully declared in the context of `MyFunctor(B)`. Obviously `B` depends on `MyFunctor(B)`, which itself depends on `B`, so I tried to use the `rec` keyword on module `B`, but it didn't work out.

So, is it possible to do something like this ? It would be useful as I have several modules `B_1, ..., B_n` that use the same implementation of `B_k.complex_func` in terms of `B_k.basic_func`.

Or is there a better pattern for my problem ? I know that I can declare `complex_impl` as a regular function taking `basic_func` as a parameter, without using a functor at all :

```
let complex_impl basic_func params =
    ...
    basic_func ...
    ...
```

But in my case `complex_impl` uses many basic functions of `A`, and I think that the paradigm of functors is clearer and less error-prone.

**Edit :** I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28687167/4514794), but in fact, `A` uses some type `t` that is specialized in `B` :

```
module type A = sig
    type t
    val basic_func: t -> unit
    val complex_func: t -> unit
end

module MyFunctor :
    functor (SomeA : A) ->
struct
    let complex_impl (x : SomeA.t) =
        SomeA.basic_func x
        ...
end

module rec B : A = struct
    type t = int
    val basic_func (x : t) = ...
    val complex_func (x : t) =
        let module Impl = MyFunctor(B) in
        Impl.complex_impl x
end
```

And now I get the error (for `x` at line `Impl.complex_impl x`) :

```
This expression has type t = int but an expression was expected of type B.t
```

**Edit 2 :** I solved this second problem with the following code :

```
module rec B :
    A with type t = int
= struct
    type t = int
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use recursive modules just like you'd write recursive `let` bindings

```
module type A = sig
    val basic_func   : unit -> int
    val complex_func : unit -> int
end

module MyFunctor =
  functor (SomeA : A) ->
  struct
    let complex_impl = SomeA.basic_func
end

module rec B : A = struct
    let basic_func () = 0
    let complex_func () =
      let module Impl = MyFunctor(B) in
      Impl.complex_impl ()
end
```

Note (a) the `module rec` bit in the definition of `B` and (b) that I am required to provide a module signature for a recursive module definition.

```
# B.basic_func ();;
- : int = 0
# B.complex_func ();;
- : int = 0
```

There's a small caveat, however, in that this only works because the signature `A` has only values which are function types. It is thus known as a "safe module". If `basic_func` and `complex_func` were values instead of function types then it would fail upon compilation

```
Error: Cannot safely evaluate the definition
       of the recursively-defined module B
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had written `module rec B = struct` and missed the `B : A` part.