# Recursive functor in OCaml

Tags: recursion, module, ocaml

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683972/mutually-recursive-module-and-functor-in-ocaml), but I want to declare a recursive functor instead of a recursive module. So I have :

An interface `A` :

```
module type A = sig
    type t
    val basic_func: ...
    val complex_func: ...
end
```

A functor `ComplexImpl` which implements `A.complex_func` in terms of `A.basic_func` :

```
module ComplexImpl (SomeA : A) =
struct
    let complex_impl params =
        SomeA.basic_func ...
        ...
end
```

Another interface `I` :

```
module type I = sig
    type t
    ...
end
```

And a functor `B` which takes an argument of type `I`, implements interface `A` and uses `ComplexImpl` to implement `complex_func`. I would like to write something like this :

```
(* I can't write 'rec' here *)
module rec B (SomeI : I) :
    A with type t = SomeI.t
= struct
    type t = SomeI.t
    (* this line does not work *)
    module Impl = ComplexImpl(B(I))

    let basic_func (x : t) = ...
    let complex_func (x : t) =
        Impl.complex_impl x
end
```

But I can't declare a recursive functor...

---

The only way I found to implement my recursive functor was to parametrize it by itself :

```
module B (SomeI : I) (CopyOfB : A with type t = SomeI.t) :
    A with type t = SomeI.t
= struct
    type t = SomeI.t
    (* this line works *)
    module Impl = ComplexImpl(CopyOfB)

    let basic_func (x : t) = ...
    let complex_func (x : t) =
        Impl.complex_impl x
end
```

And use it like this :

```
module rec RealB = B(SomeI)(RealB)
```

But the syntax is verbose, not really safe (what if someone puts a parameter different than `RealB`) and it becomes really tricky if `RealB` is itself a functor...

Answer (score 5):

There is a syntactic restriction that recursive modules have the form:

```
module rec Name : module_type = module_expr
```

which means that recursive functors cannot be declared using:

```
module rec Name (Arg : module_type) : module_type = module_expr
```

but must instead be written:

```
module rec Name : functor (Arg : module_type) -> module_type =
  functor (Arg : module_type) -> module_expr
```

Comment: However, this does not work in my case because the signature of `B(SomeI)` is `A with type t = SomeI.t`. So with your terms, `module_type` of  `Name` depends on `Arg`, which is invalid (unless I missed something).

Comment: It works fine in your case. The `module_type` of `Name` will also be of the form `functor (Arg : modtype) -> modtype` (since the type of `Name` is a functor type). I'll update my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: In my case, I get the following error : `Cannot safely evaluate the definition of the recursively-defined module B`

Comment: Your code is not necessarily well-founded because the definition of B(SomeI) involves calling B(SomeI). In the solution that you give in the question, you are taking advantage of a work around that OCaml provides -- if a module is a structure containing only functions then it allows potentially ill-founded recursion (which will raise an exception at run-time if it turns out to actually be ill-founded). This work-around is not supported for functors.

Comment: Personally, I would avoid using recursive modules if possible. Sometimes they are unavoidable but usually there is a simpler way without them

Answer (score 4):

I have found a solution :

```
module B (SomeI : I) = struct
    (* introduce a recursive module Implementation *)
    module rec Implementation :
        A with type t = SomeI.t
    = struct
        type t = SomeI.t
        (* use Implementation here *)
        module Impl = ComplexImpl(Implementation)

        let basic_func (x : t) = ...
        let complex_func (x : t) =
            Impl.complex_impl x
    end

    (* include the code of Implementation here *)
    include Implementation
end
```

And I can use it like this :

```
module RealB = B(SomeI)
```

Comment: This only works when the functor isn't actually recursive, but only it's _result_ is. The general solution is what Leo showed. It allows the functor to apply itself, even with different arguments.